# Can you ask the same question on different SE's

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have a question that is pertinent to both Scifi and fantasy SE and anime and manga SE, but I want a good answer, explanantion and discussion, so since it pertinent to both can't I post it on both?
Can I ask the same question on different SE's?

Here is a link to the question I asked 
https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/in-what-se-would-a-question-with-a-scifi-element-about-a-manga-or-anime-go

I think its a grey area.
 But that is not the only question I want to post on different sites.
Or should I ask it on Meta Stacks Exchange.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you asking it on one, then getting a mod to move it to the other...