# Is it acceptable to migrate or cross-post questions that didn't get a (good) answer in the original SE?

Tags: discussion

Given the nature of of this SE and other SE sites like "Movies & TV" or "Anime & Manga" or (possibly) "Arqade", it's pretty likely for questions that fit on one of said sites, to also be a good fit on SFF SE.

I know it's not acceptable to cross-post to multiple sites from the beginning.

However, in a situation where a question is asked on Site 1 where it is completely appropriate, but either does not receive an answer at all or a correct/good answer for a long period of time, is it considered acceptable to cross-post to Site 2 where it is also completely appropriate?

If not cross-posting, then is requesting for migration possible? Will this remove the reputation / badges / votes earned on that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question should answer yours.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/can-you-ask-the-same-question-on-different-ses)

[And this one.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-anime-and-movies-sites)

I don't know whether your question is a duplicate,but a lot of questions that are asked on the *anime and manga* and *Movies and tv* SE's are either duplicates of what is asked here or they are very closely related.

This is what was said to me about moving questions.

> There's nothing to stop you asking it on one, then getting a mod to
>   move it to the other.

[And this.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-anime-and-movies-sites)

> Cross-posting is strongly discouraged. (Strictly speaking, that's
>   multi-posting: a question is only present on one site, the SE platform
>   does not support cross-posting by design.) It might be ok occasionally
>   to ask similar questions on both sites, but the questions should be
>   tailored to each audience.